# I am getting this error in the following lines of code DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.io.file

Here I am getting an error from the using line

```
using (var filestream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(filestream).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
names.Add(name);
```

Here, I am getting an error in the if block.

```
if (files.Any())
{
    var names = await FileTransactionManager.SaveFileAsync(files, path2);
    var ancients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(getEntity.NAME);
    names.AddRange(ancients);
    getEntity.NAME = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(names.ToArray());
}
```

If I need to explain the problem in general, I get an error when trying to add files in the program. The reason for the error is in the lines of code I have described.

> That's the whole error message DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\muhasebe\Documents\GitHub\BO_Sleader2\CoreFramework.SLeader\wwwroot\klasorler\Fiyat_Listeleri\294_Haftalik_Rapor14.pdf'.

> Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this error through these codes?

Comment: If you can provide the error message will be helpful for people to help

Comment: It's in the title

Comment: Check the file path is correct or not

Comment: Just refer to the error message, The path is not correct.

Comment: I shared the exact error message I got above, where could the problem come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the directory exist: "C:\Users\muhasebe\Documents\GitHub\BO_Sleader2\CoreFramework.SLeader\wwwroot\klasorler\Fiyat_Listeleri" create it if not!

```
string path = @"C:\Users\muhasebe\Documents\GitHub\BO_Sleader2\CoreFramework.SLeader\wwwroot\klasorler\Fiyat_Listeleri\";

// or 
// string path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "klasorler\Fiyat_Listeleri")

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: You have to specify the folder, look like path2 is incorrect in your code : var names = await FileTransactionManager.SaveFileAsync(files, path2);

Comment: So, will I use the code you shared in the above code in the controller or in the class I made filetransaction, I asked a lot of questions, but thank you again.

Comment: It should go in the controller, create "path2" if it doesn't exist